# Using Crystal Quartz

Tags: c#, .net, quartz.net

I am trying to use [Crystal Quartz](https://code.google.com/p/crystal-quartz/) I downloaded the source with,

```
svn checkout http://crystal-quartz.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ crystal-quartz-read-only
```

But When I try to run the project demo, after click the "View CrystalQuartz Panel -->" on the default page I get 404 not found error from iis.

It seems to be trying to access CrystalQuartzPanel.axd, but this doesn't exist.
Has anyone used this before and know how to get it to work?

Comment: SO is a Q&A website for programming questions.  This type of question isnt really a fit here as its about installing software.  You may find help over at [Super User](http://superuser.com)

Answer (score 0):

There's no such folder in trunk

Open this in browser: http://crystal-quartz.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/
Or check out the whole trunk